# Any way other than Win32::OLE to call objects from dll in Perl?

Tags: perl, winapi

[`Win32::OLE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::OLE) is not thread safe. Is there a way to go around it?

Can the following typical `Win32::OLE` usage be replaced by any other Perl modules?

```
my $myWin32 = Win32::OLE->new('my_App');
my $myApp1  = Win32::OLE->GetObject("my_App");
my $myApp2  = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject("my_App");
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not thread safe? The default initialization method is documented to be `COINIT_MULTITHREADED`, which "creates a multi-threaded apartment that will be shared with any other threads that repeat [the call to `CoInitializeEx`]."

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [`Win32::API`](https://metacpan.org/release/Win32-API), but I'm not sure of its thread safety.